# HTML Nested Table structure

Tags: html, html-table

I am looking to create a table structure like below;

[image]

Note, I have just shown BodyRow1 here, but all the columns in the body rows have something (mostly textboxes)

I have created them using

```
<thead>, <tbody> and <tfoot>
```

I have added the last 3 rows under `<tfoot>`

However, I am in 2 minds over whether to create a separate table under the tfoot and add those 3 rows OR use the same parent table structure for that.

Now here's the thing which makes it a bit hard,

1. The FooterTxtBox1 & FooterTxtBox2 are not at all related to the body rows above. So FooterTxtBox1 can be longer & not have to be constrained by BodyRow1
2. But ColSubTotal1 & ColSubTotal2 are actually totals of that column, so have to be aligned with those columns.

What would be the recommended approach to follow ? I am not looking at the code, but just wanted the approach which you think would be more appropriate?

Comment: Use 1) and never 2)

Comment: *FooterTxtBox1 & FooterTxtBox2 are not at all related to the body rows above* - you mean the footer cells are not related to the columns? Techically you could squeeze them there via merging the cells (and splitting again, perhaps), but are they really supposed to be inside that table?

Comment: With your rep level, I would have thought you would know better than to ask for opinion here. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the lesser evil is to keep them in the same table. You'd want unsighted users to be able to navigate to the total cells within the same context as their header cells.   You could place the footers in a caption element and use a negative margin to visually place it alongside the totals if you wish, though you would have to take care not to let the footers overlap the totals. Something like this:

```css
table {
  border:1px solid;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
caption {
  text-align:left;
  margin-top:-23px;
  margin-left:3px;
}
caption span {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 10px;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:150px;
}
td, th {
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <caption><span>FooterTxtBox1</span><span>FooterTxtBox2</span>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Col Head 1<th>Col Head 2<th>Col Head 3
        <th>Col Head 4<th>Col Head 5
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>BodyRow 1<td><td><td><td>
      <tr><td>BodyRow 2<td><td><td><td>
    <tfoot>
      <tr><td>FooterBtn1<td>FooterBtn1<td><td><td>
      <tr><td colspan=3><td>ColSubTotal1<td>ColSubTotal2
      <tr><td colspan=4><td>Total
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks...Only issue with that approach is the alignment of FooterTxtBox1/FooterTxtBox2 which are not related to the cols above. How do I adjust their widths freely ?

Comment: @testndtv - I don't follow. The widths of FooterTxtBox1/FooterTxtBox2 are freely adjustable and are not constrained by the column widths.

Comment: What I meant is how to make FooterTxtBox1 a bit unrelated to BodyRow 1 i.e. say I want BodyRow 1 to occupy lesser space, but want FooterTxtBox1 to be a bit bigger

Comment: @testndtv  - And what I mean is they already don't occupy the same space. I've added some borders and widths. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: You do realize you are replying to an off topic question asking for opinion...right? Why do you do that so often? More than any one I know.

Comment: @Rob. - The key part of my answer is the second sentence. This matters. It's not simply an opinion but a necessary technical solution to a real world problem. The rest of the answer is simply a description of how the OP can get the layout they want within that constraint.

Comment: The **question** is off topic and shouldn't be answered at all!

Comment: @Rob - The answer is important. If you feel strongly about it, fix the question to make it on topic.

Comment: Not my job. Not your job either. Don't answer off topic questions. That is your job.

Answer (score 0):

*HTML Nested Table structure* - you can nest a table after all, especially if borders are not needed. Though they are enabled there to show what went where:

```html
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Col Head 1<th>Col Head 2<th>Col Head 3<th>Col Head 4<th>Col Head 5<th>Col Head 6
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>BodyRow1
    <tr><td>BodyRow2
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td>FooterBtn1<td>FooterBtn1
    <tr><td colspan=4><td>ColSubTotal1<td>ColSubTotal2
    <tr><td colspan=5>
      <table width=100%><tr><td>FooterTxtBox1<td>FooterTxtBox2</table>
    <td>Total
</table>
```